# Installing Ogre3D in Ubuntu 13.04 x64?

Tags: installation, 3d, sdk

I'm using code::blocks. I'm a C++ developer, and I need Ogre3D for a project I'm working on. I've heard of Ogre before, and the demo applications are impressive, so I have decided to use it. THe problem is, I can't install it. The Linux downloads page is a mix-mash of different tutorials that don't work or return "file not found" errors. I'm confused beyond belief as to how I actually set the thing up - the SDK is refusing to install despite installing libogre-dev with apt.

Please, please can someone make clear what I'm actually meant to do? I've been searching the web and trying different things for 48 hours now, and have got nowhere. I can't even compile the example application, it says "Exampleapplication.h: file or directory not found" when compiling with code::blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Ogre3D 1.9 in OpenMW launchpad PPA. Go to terminal and call each command (you will have to confirm addition of new PPA, wait for repositories database to update and then confirm the installation of new packages):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openmw/openmw
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev libogre-1.9.0 libboost1.54-dev libboost-thread1.54-dev
```

Works in Ubuntu GNOME 13.10, it probably will work in earlier versions as well but might require to install more dependencies - just add every package it complains about in `sudo apt-get install` call.

In Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 package is already in repositories so all you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev
```